# How can we receive hashtx and hashblock from bitcoind by zmq subscribe?

Tags: bitcoind, zeromq

1. install bitcoind by sudo apt install bitcoind in Ubuntu 16.04 server amd64(https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#ubuntu-1410)
2. bitcoind --version show v0.13 ga402396
3. bitcoind -daemon -zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332 -zmqpubhashtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
   after download, blocks file is 89G.
   and the bitcoin.conf only have rpcuser=xxxyyy and rpcpassword=xxx123
   should add server=1 to bitcoin.conf?
4. git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin
5. cd bitcoin/contrib/zmq and pip install zmq, then do python zmq_sub.py and we can't receive anything in long wait.
   How can we receive hashtx and hashblock from bitcoind? Should i install libzmq3-dev? Is libzmq3-dev only for compile bitcoind and don't need in runtime?

Answer (score 4):

The PPA you have installed (https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin/+packages) is not compiled with ZMQ support (It should in future).

You need to self-compile bitcoin v0.13.0 or use one of the "official" binaries: https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.13.0/

**EDIT: since 0.14, ZMQ support is available via the PPA**

Comment: Note that, latest packages from `ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin` contain ZMQ support